# How to perform calculation based on index?

Tags: python, pandas

Im very new to Python, hopefully someone can help to solve this issue.
Im trying to create a calculation in power bi based on my index. The reason for that is because my index resets from 1 to 250 every time one of my columns has a new value. kind of index by category.
Index: Trade day (1 to 250)
Catogory; [contract year] 2008 - 2019 for each year the index resets.
Value: Price

```
Table/Raw Data structure
Trade Day Year  Norm_Price
1         2008   1.87
2         2008   1.84
3         2008   1.87
.         2008   1.88
.         2008   1.88
250       2008   1.22
1         2009   1.35
2         2009   1.32
3         2009   1.78
.         2009   1.55
.         2009   1.77
250       2009   1.23
and so on
```

I successfully ran two functions but my issue is that when my index goes back to one the calculations continues as there is no index. How can i approach that?

This is my code

1st calculation/new column it works fine but when my index column goes back to one it performs the calculation from 250 to 1 which i dont want. for each time trade day is equal to 1 i need my new column to be 0

```
dataset.loc[0,'Percent_Change'] = 0

for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
    dataset.loc[i,'Percent_Change'] = (dataset.loc[i,'Norm_Price'] - dataset.loc[i-1,'Norm_Price']) / dataset.loc[i-1,'Norm_Price']
```

2nd calculation/new column
for each time trade day is equal to 1 i need my new column to be 1

```
dataset.loc[0,'Norm_Change'] = 1

for i in range(1, len(dataset)):
    dataset.loc[i,'Norm_Change'] = dataset.loc[i-1,'Norm_Change'] + (dataset.loc[i,'Percent_Change'] * dataset.loc[i-1,'Norm_Change'])
```

if its too difficult to make it perform the calculation based on index, maybe a if statement?

if trade day = 1 then 1 else perform function in i ??

Any help will help tremendously!

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can do with `groupby`:

```
df['Percent_Change'] = df.groupby('Year')['Norm_Price'].pct_change().fillna(0)

df['Norm_Change'] = df['Percent_Change'].add(1).groupby(df['Year']).cumprod()
```

Output:

```
   Trade Day  Year  Norm_Price  Percent_Change  Norm_Change
0          1  2008        1.87        0.000000     1.000000
1          2  2008        1.84       -0.016043     0.983957
2          3  2008        1.87        0.016304     1.000000
3          .  2008        1.88        0.005348     1.005348
4          .  2008        1.88        0.000000     1.005348
5        250  2008        1.22       -0.351064     0.652406
6          1  2009        1.35        0.000000     1.000000
7          2  2009        1.32       -0.022222     0.977778
8          3  2009        1.78        0.348485     1.318519
9          .  2009        1.55       -0.129213     1.148148
10         .  2009        1.77        0.141935     1.311111
11       250  2009        1.23       -0.305085     0.911111
```

Comment: I get this error NameError: name 'df' is not defined. how do i define df?

Comment: DataSource.Error: ADO.NET: Python script error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonScriptWrapper.PY", line 12, in <module>
    df['Percent_Change'] = df.groupby('Contract_Year')['Norm_Price'].pct_change().fillna(0)
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Details:
    DataSourceKind=Python
    DataSourcePath=Python
    Message=Python script error.

Comment: df is your dataset. Change all `df` to `dataset`

Comment: Thanks so much!! that worked perfectly! I have a lot of studying to do to understand pandas better!